# Spring batch slave step executing infinitely causing partition job waiting for updating status

Tags: spring-batch

I have spring-batch with spring boot application to process 60-70 millions of data. Application was built for using spring batch partitioning. I need to read customer ids from a file  and then read some reference data from redis and oarcle DB and apply some business logic and write to PG DB .
Application working as expected and all our system testing completed. But when we went to PT testing we see few slave steps hang at random place(not consistent with file or line number). Step_execution table version keep increment but no data process. I have tried between 50-1000 partition with 5-25 million data . Only for 1 million a with 36 partition I was able to get completed status for all slaves and partition step. What might be the reason to hang some slave steps. If I re-run the job issue is not consistent like always not the same file(slave) hangs neither same number of slaves hang.

Comment: Do you know where is the slave step hanging? Have you enabled the `--debug` flag to see where is the issue happening?

Comment: @ Mahmoud Ben Hassine how to enable debug flag? you mean debug logs?. I am not sure where it is hanging actually

Comment: @Mahmoud Ben Hassine I missed one point to mention, i have skiplistners and all 3 methods will write skipped record to file(error file) and at the end in jobnotification listener after job method error file is uploaded to AWS s3. All partitions are writing to same error file

Comment: yes I mean debug logs. Since you are using Spring Boot you can add `--debug` flag to your command. The idea is to know where exactly the step is hanging.

Comment: this is happening in PT where we have large data....IT looks fine...so we have not enabled debug it PT let me check that option

Comment: I don't mean in which environment it is happening, I mean through the logs you can see where the step is hanging, aka in which statement in the code exactly. Without this, I really can't see how we can help.